# Add Custom Function to WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Two questions here.

Below is a function in WooCommerce wc-order-functions.php that I found works almost similar to what I need.

```
function wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $order_key ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Faster than get_posts()
    $order_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_order_key' AND meta_value = %s", $order_key ) );

    return $order_id;
}
```

Which returns the `$order_id` but I'm looking to get the `$order_key` so that I can contruct the url generated after buyer have click the 'Place order' button on the checkout page e.g. `domain.com/checkout/order-received/2316/?key=wc_order_54c7142660e24`

`wc_order_54c7142660e24` being the `$order_id` and
`2316` being the `$order_key`

I know that the SQL command below gets the value I want from database:

```
function wc_get_order_key_by_order_id( $order_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Faster than get_posts()
    $order_key = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_value FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_order_key' AND post_id = %s", $order_id ) );

    return $order_key;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to hook the filter to wordpress functions.php So this is my first question.

Second question is I've been searching for the function that might be responsible for generating the meta_value for the `$order_key` but can't seem to find it, would be great to know how it works. I suppose the first way is kinda redundant since the function I'm looking for already exists, just can't seem to locate it.

Comment: I have tried just adding that function to functions.php without hooking to anything andcall the value without any problem, tho not sure if it's the right way. Any advice on this?

Comment: I have found the responsible function for the url I wanted here [link](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_abstract_orderget_checkout_order_received_url/)

But when I tried to echo `WC_Abstract_Order::get_checkout_order_received_url();` from the thankyou page, the url is incomplete e.g. `domain.com/checkout/order-received/bacs2` bacs2 is the id for my custom gateway plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your woocommerce template files where you need that link:

```
echo get_site_url().'/checkout/order-received/'.$order->id.'&key='.$order->order_key;
```

Comment: Try to format your code blocks. And for ease of understanding for future readers, improve your answer by explaining why it works and why it solves the problem.